# Перевод строчки `It's okay to email me`

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, регистрация

Переведите, пожалуйста, строчку `It's okay to email me`:

> [image: скриншот строки без перевода]

Спасибо.

Answer (score 4):

Перевёл как:

> Согласен на отправку мне писем.

Будет на сайте после подкачки Transifex и пересборки сайта.

Comment: Я что-то не уверен насчёт единственного числа («отправку»). Может, лучше «Мне можно писать по подтверждённому адресу»/«Stackoverflow можно писать мне на этот адрес»?

Comment: Для меня «Согласен на отправку мне письма» звучит как «Я согласен с тем, что SO отправит мне прямо сейчас письмо».

Comment: @VladD надо посмотреть, что по ссылке «подробнее» отображается для прояснения деталей, одно там письмо или несколько.

Comment: @VladD исправил на множественное число. В общем случае должно покрывать ситуацию. По ссылке «подробнее» (там тоже ни фига не переведено, кстати) окошко про ненависть к спаму. Однозначно не понятно, связана ли эта галочка с настройками рассылок или просто разрешает связываться по email с участником.

Comment: Формальное слово "Согласен" после галочки по русской традиции намекает на обязательность простановки галочки... Надо что-нибудь менее формальное.

Comment: @PavelMayorov обязательность в упомянутых Вами случаях подразумевает невозможность продолжения регистрации (например, блокировка кнопки). Тут же такого нет.

Comment: @alexolut в том-то и проблема, что такого нет, а намек на это есть.

Comment: @PavelMayorov «не возражаю»?

Comment: @alexolut да, я думаю что так будет лучше.